# How to read the "Lilit Phra Lo" (Thai: ลิลิตพระลอ) verses?

Tags: reading, thai-language

How are the "songs" or "verses" (or indented sections) to be read in this Thai epic?

https://vajirayana.org/%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%9E%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B0%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%AD/%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%9E%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B0%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%AD

Is it read "left right left right", or "left left left left, right right right right", for each numbered verse?

For example, there are two verses here:

[image]

Do you read, for each "verse block", read the left chunk top-to-bottom first, then the right chunk (4 lines each in the first verse above), or do you read left/right/left/right moving like an English text?

Same with [this one](https://vajirayana.org/%E0%B9%82%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A8%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%A0%E0%B8%B8%E0%B8%8D%E0%B8%8A%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%A2/%E0%B9%82%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A8%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%A0%E0%B8%B8%E0%B8%8D%E0%B8%8A%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%A2):

[image]

Comment: Is this not clearly answered by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilit_Phra_Lo), which says that the poem contains sections in the โคลง (khlong) form, in which each บาท (line) has two วรรค (half-lines).

Comment: No it doesn't, where did you find that?

Comment: It seems to say what you are saying [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_poetry#Khlong).

Comment: Yes, that's where I got it from.